# EF Core TPC mapping of entity and derived entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have EF Core entities which are defined as [TPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-concrete-type-configuration).

Entities:

```cs
public class Customer
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<ProformaInvoice> ProformaInvoices { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public double Value { get; set; }
  public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class ProformaInvoice : Invoice       // configured as TPC
{
  public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    var customerBuilder = builder.Entity<Customer>();
    customerBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    customerBuilder.HasMany(x => x.ProformaInvoices).WithOne(x => x.Customer).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    customerBuilder.HasMany(x => x.Invoices).WithOne(x => x.Customer).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    var invoiceBuilder = builder.Entity<Invoice>();
    invoiceBuilder.UseTpcMappingStrategy();             // TPC
    invoiceBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    invoiceBuilder.Property(x => x.Value).IsRequired();

    var proformaInvoiceBuilder = builder.Entity<ProformaInvoice>();
    //proformaInvoiceBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);         // do not configure key else get error "A key cannot be configured on 'ProformaInvoice' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'Invoice'."
    proformaInvoiceBuilder.Property(x => x.Value).IsRequired();
    proformaInvoiceBuilder.Property(x => x.Notes).IsRequired();
  }

  public DbSet<Customer> Customers => Set<Customer>();
  public DbSet<ProformaInvoice> ProformaInvoices => Set<ProformaInvoice>();
  public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices => Set<Invoice>();

}
```

Create migration:

```bash
$ dotnet ef migrations add AddEntities
```

Error:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'Customer.Invoices' and 'Invoice.Customer' because a relationship already exists between 'Customer.ProformaInvoices' and 'ProformaInvoice.Customer'. Navigations can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'Invoice.Customer' first in 'OnModelCreating'.

How do I fix this? I suspect this has something to do with the TPC design.

(Note I cannot change to TPH/TPT, I need to use TPC... this just a simplified minimal repro.)

Comment: In anticipation of a standard SO criticism... Unfortunately I cannot "change the design" as it represents a legacy system outside of my control. :-)

Comment: Do you understand that `Customer.Invoices` includes the `ProformaInvoices`?

Comment: @GertArnold I suspected that but wasn't sure - thank you for clarifying. That is not what I want. How do I "separate" them? There is not much info on TPC yet... From what I've seen on the EF community standups, using TPC like I've done - to do 1:1 mapping from object space to database space while keeping the entities DRY - is a supported feature. But I'm unsure how to do that?

Comment: Can you please show the existing/desired database schema?

Comment: Which design you cannot change - database, entity model, both? I doubt someone could demand TPC. As I understand, you have two separate tables, having "common" set of similar fields. You don't need EF inheritance for that. Just use them as separate entities, the fact that you want them to be linked to separate collections is against the OO oriented rules that Collection<Base> includes both Base and Derived. EFC inheritance strategies do not violate that rule, just change how the hierarchy is *stored* in the database.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for your explanation. In the [community standup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaL6DKW1mrg) (I can't find the exact timestamp right now) they said that using TPC just to model separate entities like I've done is supported... But what I showed above does not work for the reasons you explained. How would I model two classes as above which have completely separate tables? (That means not TPH or TPT, which is why I tried the new TPC.) It's probably so simple I'm overthinking it.

Comment: @lonix See below. Tried to cover all possible at this time mapping options, hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance represents the "is a" relationship, which means that derived can be used anywhere as base substitute. EF Core inheritance strategies just change the way object hierarchy is stored/retrieved to/from database, but do not break that rule, so both `DbSet<Base>` and `ICollection<Base>` will also include (and allow adding) Derived elements as well.

Which means that of you want to distinguish two entity type sets/collections, their element entity types (note *entity* types, not CLR types) should not have inheritance relationship.

In EF Core you have the following mapping options:

First is to not use any EFC inheritance strategy, which is achieved with [HasBaseType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.hasbasetype?view=efcore-7.0) fluent API and passing `null` type (in other words, saying "This entity type have no base entity entity, even though the class inherits from it), e.g.

```cs
var invoiceBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>();
invoiceBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
invoiceBuilder.Property(x => x.Value).IsRequired();

var proformaInvoiceBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<ProformaInvoice>();
proformaInvoiceBuilder.HasBaseType((Type)null);
proformaInvoiceBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
proformaInvoiceBuilder.Property(x => x.Value).IsRequired();
proformaInvoiceBuilder.Property(x => x.Notes).IsRequired();

var customerBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>();
customerBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
customerBuilder.HasMany(x => x.Invoices).WithOne(x => x.Customer).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
customerBuilder.HasMany(x => x.ProformaInvoices).WithOne(x => x.Customer).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

However note that this line

```cs
customerBuilder.HasMany(x => x.ProformaInvoices).WithOne(x => x.Customer).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

*must* be after

```cs
proformaInvoiceBuilder.HasBaseType((Type)null);
```

otherwise you'll get the same "navigation property used" exception. Which could be problematic if you use entity type configuration classes and have no control of the order of the execution. Hence it is better to configure these relationships from the other side (after configuring the involved entity), e.g. (now these could be in any order)

```cs
var customerBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>();
customerBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

var invoiceBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>();
invoiceBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
invoiceBuilder.Property(x => x.Value).IsRequired();
invoiceBuilder.HasOne(x => x.Customer).WithMany(x => x.Invoices).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

var proformaInvoiceBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<ProformaInvoice>();
proformaInvoiceBuilder.HasBaseType((Type)null);
proformaInvoiceBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
proformaInvoiceBuilder.Property(x => x.Value).IsRequired();
proformaInvoiceBuilder.Property(x => x.Notes).IsRequired();
proformaInvoiceBuilder.HasOne(x => x.Customer).WithMany(x => x.ProformaInvoices).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Second option is to move the common data to a *separate* abstract class and let the two inherit from it, e.g.

```cs
public abstract class BaseInvoice
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice : BaseInvoice
{
}

public class ProformaInvoice : BaseInvoice
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

and use any of the above fluent configurations with just `HasBaseType((Type)null)` removed, since now the base of the two entities is just a class not mapped as entity.

Or, now you can map that class as entity and TPC strategy

```cs
var customerBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>();
customerBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

var baseInvoiceBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<BaseInvoice>();
baseInvoiceBuilder.UseTpcMappingStrategy();
baseInvoiceBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
baseInvoiceBuilder.Property(x => x.Value).IsRequired();

var invoiceBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>();
invoiceBuilder.HasOne(x => x.Customer).WithMany(x => x.Invoices).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

var proformaInvoiceBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<ProformaInvoice>();
proformaInvoiceBuilder.Property(x => x.Notes).IsRequired();
proformaInvoiceBuilder.HasOne(x => x.Customer).WithMany(x => x.ProformaInvoices).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Just keep in mind the base entity along with the strategy *must* be configured *before* the derived entities. As well as base properties, key etc. must be configured there and not in derived entities. This, along with the fact that TPC expects the keys to be unique across the tables, hence regular "identity" columns cannot be used, and needs shared sequence instead, all this just to provide you a union query which you probably don't need, makes the TPC useless for me. But anyway, above is the way you can use it if insisting.

In all the cases, you can verify the correctness of the mappings by checking the generated SQL. For instance, both

```cs
dbContext.Set<Invoice>().ToQueryString()

dbContext.Set<ProformaInvoice>().ToQueryString()
```

should query only the corresponding table

```sql
SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[Value], [i].[CustomerId]
FROM [Invoices] AS [i]

SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Value], [p].[CustomerId], [p].[Notes]
FROM [ProformaInvoices] AS [p]
```

and both

```cs
dbContext.Set<Customer>().SelectMany(c => c.Invoices).ToQueryString()

dbContext.Set<Customer>().SelectMany(c => c.ProformaInvoices).ToQueryString()
```

should join only to the corresponding table

```sql
SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[Value], [i].[CustomerId]
FROM [Customers] AS [c]
INNER JOIN [Invoices] AS [i] ON [c].[Id] = [i].[CustomerId]

SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Value], [p].[CustomerId], [p].[Notes]
FROM [Customers] AS [c]
INNER JOIN [ProformaInvoices] AS [p] ON [c].[Id] = [p].[CustomerId]
```

and only and only if you used the very last mapping of `BaseInvoice` as TPC base entity, the following

```cs
dbContext.Set<BaseInvoice>().ToQueryString()
```

should produce a union of the two

```sql
SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[Value], [i].[CustomerId], NULL AS [CustomerId0], NULL AS [Notes], N'Invoice' AS [Discriminator]
FROM [Invoices] AS [i]
UNION ALL
SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Value], NULL AS [CustomerId], [p].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId0], [p].[Notes], N'ProformaInvoice' AS [Discriminator]
FROM [ProformaInvoices] AS [p]
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan for this comprehensive answer! `HasBaseType` is what I was looking for. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#entity-type-hierarchy-mapping) cover it briefly but not as well as in your answer.